# How can I get Adobe .pdx file to work online?

Tags: search, indexing, acrobat

Have thoroughly googled this topic without any luck finding a workable solution. On my laptop I created a folder containing a collection of 280 PDF documents. Within that folder are two additional files created when I ran a `"Full Text Index With Catalog"` using `Adobe Acrobat XI Pro: .LOG and .PDX` files. Also within the folder is a sub-folder containing index.idx and index1.idx. The index1.idx contains all the results of the search index. The index works great when operating locally on my laptop.

My aim is to make this PDF collection available to the public. I uploaded the entire folder to my website and created a webpage with a link to the .PDX file expecting the search index to work on the website the way it works on my laptop. No such luck! Using both Firefox and Chrome yields pretty much the same results: the PDX file tries to open files on my computer rather than the set of files stored on the website. Here's what happens depending on whether the PDX is opened with Acrobat or Reader:

1. "You have chosen to open this PDX file. Open with ..." I selected Adobe Acrobat. This results in an error message:

> "Search could not load the index
>   (C:\Users\Name\AppData\Local\Temp\library.pdx.

You may need to rebuild this index."

2. If I try to open the .PDX by navigating to the Adobe Reader software on my computer (AcrRd32.exe), I get the following:

> "The operation you are trying to perform potentially requires read
>   access to your drives. Do you want to allow this operation?

How can I get this to work from the website? Alternatively, are there other options out there to achieve the same result?

Comment: Ugh... had the same question, found this disappointing answer - better to know than not know. I'm preparing a structured group of documents for a trial into a web=page like structure on a USB drive or web server running off a laptop (accessible by a local wifi link from a tablet or PC used by the lawyers or judge in court). You open then index.html file and it opens a web page that is a table of contents that links to each PDF file. Wanted to add an index and link to the PDX file so you could do an index search of the whole collection. Bummer.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I get this to work from the website?

You can't.

The index created by Acrobat is designed to work with the desktop versions of Acrobat and Reader. However, there are a number of search engines that index PDF files including Google but none of them will open and highlight the search terms like you see in Acrobat/Reader.

Comment: Thanks for the disappointing news. Now you would think that there would be a demand for that capability. I'd even pay Adobe extra to be able to use it on my website!

Comment: Adobe licenses the indexing technology. If I recall correctly, they are contractually prohibited from making the indices available to other search engines... at least that was the case when I worked there. It may have changed but I doubt it.